# How to separate these two processes?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, wcf, web-services, concurrency

I have an asp.net website that stores events inside a database table. Then I have a windows service app that reads those events and performs appropriate actions. Currently its possible for the two processes to insert and remove records from the same table at the same time.

What is a better pattern for developing such a system so to insure the two are never working on the same table simultaneously?

Comment: @abatishchev I use mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about pattern but I'd do a WCF-service and let both use that to access the data. Then share a common lock object between all methods that alter (or read) the table contents.

Comment: Could I have the asp.net app call web service methods to the WCF service on the same machine or does the WCF machine have to be on a separate server?

Comment: It can be on the same machine. It will just be on a different port.

Answer (score 0):

For this scenario I use a pattern in that ensures that the data cannot be updated concurrently.

I always add a special column to the table, usually 'LastModified' of type 'timestamp'. When adding or inserting a row I always set this column.

When I come to update a record I make sure that the stored procedure checks the value that I am passing in with that stored in the database. If these are different then another user or process has altered this row, and I raise a concurrency error.

This can be propergated up to the calling process or handled in your service.

Answer (score 0):

This could be an architecture problem more than anything else.

Why would you need two processes that delete records?

You generally don't need two different processes to CRUD data in the same tables. One thing you can do is wrap the database/tables with a service, then let all processes that require working with the data use that service. The service can then take care of the serialization of calls. Either way, there will be only 1 process working with the DB directly.

Additionally, it sounds to me like you're in an event-sourcing type of architecture, which makes me wonder why you'd need to delete records in the first place...

Comment: I'm event sourcing but I'm not that type of architect, this problem suits this type of design. Also not both processes delete records. Only one does. Thanks for the response.